# GD using wrong color if the image is bigger

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I'm trying to generate an image by reading characters from a file and setting pixels accordingly. Everything works fine if I input data that represents e.g. a 50 by 50 px image. But if I enter something bigger e.g. 200 x 200 it's using the wrong color to fill the land!

Small example:
[50x50 Data pastebin](http://pastebin.com/M5pdvDrE)
[image]
Big Example:
[200x200 Data pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bcr0SX30)
[image]

and the code:

```
<?php

$scale=2;
$file = file_get_contents('data');
$rows = explode("\n", $file);

$land = "x"; $water="o";

$width=0;
$height=count($rows);

$index=0;
foreach($rows as $row){
    $rows[$index] = preg_split('//', $rows[$index]);
    $index++;
    $width=$index;
}

$img = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
$color1 = imagecolorallocate($img, 139,69,19);
$color2 = imagecolorallocate($img, 10,25,255);


for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++){
    $x=-1;
    $y=$i;
    foreach($rows[$i] as $key => $char){
        $landMultiplier = 1;
        $waterMultiplier=1;
        switch ($char){
            case $land:
                if($rows[$i][$key-1]==$water || $rows[$i][$key+1]==$water || $rows[$i-1][$key]==$water ){
                    $landMultiplier = -20;
                }elseif($rows[$i][$key-2]==$water || $rows[$i][$key+2]==$water || $rows[$i-2][$key]==$water ){
                    $landMultiplier = -10;
                }
                $r = max(0,min(255,rand(130,139) + $landMultiplier));
                $g = max(0,min(255,rand(60,69) + $landMultiplier));
                $b = max(0,min(255,rand(10,19) + $landMultiplier));
                $color1 = imagecolorallocate($img,$r ,$g,$b);
                imagesetpixel($img,$x,$y,$color1);
                break;
            case $water: 
                $color2 = imagecolorallocate($img, rand(0,10),rand(0,25),255);
                imagesetpixel($img,$x,$y,$color2);
                break;
        }
        $x++;
    }
}
$new_img = imagecreate($scale * $width,$scale * $height);
imagecopyresized($new_img,$img,0,0,0,0,$scale * $width,$scale * $height,$width,$height);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($new_img);
?>
```

Comment: Looks nice, any code to back it up? EDIT: np, just add the code, and you good to go :)

Comment: put your code please?

Comment: @Naruto i totally forgot to add the script... my bad... i'm editing it.

Comment: @Anant Added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 4th line from the end to:

```
$new_img = imagecreatetruecolor(...);
```

and it all works.

[image]